# How can I put 14 images in two vertical columns with a caption under each image with the images also lined up on each row using HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, image, drupal

Currently updating a post on a website that uses Drupal Cloud. I am able to use the css_injector tool to add css to the page the post will be at and can use HTML in the post. [I am trying to get something that looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qpg1w.jpg) but instead [it's looking like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8whh6.jpg)

The captions are only centered under some of the images (should be every image) and the images aren't lining up horizontally on each row. All images are the same size and I'd like it to be so that if the browser window is smaller than the width of the post, the images stay put rather than jump out of line.

In JSFiddle the output looks fine but on the webpage it doesn't. The widths of the images are less than half of the width of the container on the page, the captions are smaller than the widths of the images, so I don't understand why they aren't lining up. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's my CSS and HTML:

```css
ul {
 list-style: none;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  display: table-row;
}
figure {display:inline}
figcaption {display:block}
figure.left {float:left}
figure.right {float:right}

.left {
float: center;
border: none;
padding: 10px;
margin:0px;
}
figcaption {
text-align:center;
width: 360px;
}
.right {
float: center;
border: none;
padding: 10px;
margin:0px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/ExplainingDesign.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Explaining Reactor Design" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/ExplainingDesign.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Explaining the design of the MIT reactor</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NaturalRadFacts.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Surprised about natural radiation facts" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NaturalRadFacts.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Participants were surprised about facts where everyday sources of natural radiation can be found</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/QsFromAllAges.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Answering questions from all ages" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/QsFromAllAges.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
 <figcaption><span>Answering questions from all ages!</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/MultipleStaff.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Multiple staff members on hand" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/MultipleStaff.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Multiple staff members were on hand to field insightful questions from attendees</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyDemo.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Demonstrating how spectroscopy works" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyDemo.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
 <figcaption><span>Demonstrating how spectroscopy works</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NewConcept.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Spectroscopy was a new concept" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NewConcept.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Spectroscopy was a new concept for many visitors</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HSstudents.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="High school students asking questions" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HSstudents.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
 <figcaption><span>High school students took the opportunity to ask about what it&#39;s like to work at the reactor</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/AnsweringwithaSmile.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Surprised about natural radiation facts" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/AnsweringwithaSmile.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Answering questions with a smile!</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/YoungestAttendees.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Youngest attendees" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/YoungestAttendees.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
 <figcaption><span>Our youngest attendees enjoying their time at the event</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/GeigerExplanation.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Geiger counter explanation" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/GeigerExplanation.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Explaining how a Geiger counter works to detect radiation using natural sources (such as granite) as examples</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyExplanation.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Explaining spectroscopy" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyExplanation.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
 <figcaption><span>Explaining how spectroscopy gives you a readout of what gamma rays are being emitted from a source and how you can use that to find out what kind of isotope they belong to</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HappytoHelp.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Happy to help" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HappytoHelp.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Our staff members were more than happy to help answer questions from the public and teach them about nuclear science and technology</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
 <li>
 <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyDisplay.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Spectroscopy display" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyDisplay.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
 <figcaption><span>The display from the spectroscopy station showing the gamma ray spectrum of an orange Fiestaware cup. The red peaks on the display show the gamma rays being emitted from the radioactive decay of the natural uranium used in the glaze on the cup</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>

 <figure class="right"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HandsOnApproach.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Hands-on approach" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HandsOnApproach.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

 <figcaption><span>Giving a hands-on approach to detecting radiation using a Geiger counter and natural sources of radiation</span></figcaption>
 <span> </span></figure>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Try using bootstrap table (have a [look](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_table_basic&stacked=h)) or create custom CSS.

Comment: layout changes on smaller screen, because there is not enough space for images to display, as example change in your css-code ul {width:900px;} and it works

Comment: @JavierGonzalez Unfortunately that didn't work on the website. [Here's what it looks like when the ul width is changed to 900px in the css.](http://i.imgur.com/m9ftRDP.png) This screenshot also shows the placement of where the post is on the page and the space constraints I'm working with (but, again, the images are less than half of width of the part of the page they're going on and yet aren't lining up nicely horizontally)

Comment: @Hearty I've been trying to figure out what CSS would work to get things the way I want them, which is the CSS I've posted in my question. I searched a bunch of different forums and answers and I just don't understand why in JSFiddle it's looking fine but in practice it's not. No clue what CSS to use.

Comment: You have to change the width of all the elements that affects this ul in your css code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. I finally figured out something that works! I used [Hearty](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4790490/hearty)'s suggestion but kept my height and width constrictions in my HTML because I couldn't have the boxes go out of the white space and stretch out the page. The pictures are now nice in two vertical columns and on the same level as each other in each row.

However, I still don't know why some of the figcaption values aren't centered under the corresponding picture, though. I tried adding in a class to each figcaption to help but it's not working. I made the post live, [you can view it here.](https://nrl.mit.edu/announcements/2016/photos-from-our-nuclear-science-and-technology-qa-mit-open-house-event) I'll stop being finicky and just leave it as it is for now unless anyone has a suggestion how I can center all of the figcaptions. Thanks!

```css
img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
  width: 360px;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/ExplainingDesign.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Explaining Reactor Design" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/ExplainingDesign.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>

   <figcaption class="center"><span>Explaining the design of the MIT reactor</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NaturalRadFacts.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Surprised about natural radiation facts" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NaturalRadFacts.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>Participants were surprised about facts where everyday sources of natural radiation can be found</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/QsFromAllAges.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Answering questions from all ages" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/QsFromAllAges.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>Answering questions from all ages!</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/MultipleStaff.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Multiple staff members on hand" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/MultipleStaff.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>Multiple staff members were on hand to field insightful questions from attendees</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyDemo.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Demonstrating how spectroscopy works" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/SpectroscopyDemo.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>Demonstrating how spectroscopy works</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NewConcept.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Spectroscopy was a new concept" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/NewConcept.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>Spectroscopy was a new concept for many visitors</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HSstudents.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="High school students asking questions" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/HSstudents.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>High school students took the opportunity to ask about what it&#39;s like to work at the reactor</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
   <td>
   <figure class="left"><span><a href="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/AnsweringwithaSmile.jpg" target="_blank"><img alt="Answering questions with a smile" src="http://nrl.mit.edu/sites/default/files/images/AnsweringwithaSmile.jpg" style="width: 370px; height: 276px" /></a> </span>
   <figcaption class="center"><span>Answering questions with a smile!</span></figcaption>
   <span> </span></figure>
   </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: Try`td{  text-align:center;}` instead, check updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z64t6aj4/1/)

Comment: I did, but it won't be public until my reputation is higher or something since I'm a new user (according to the alert I get whenever I try)

Comment: Okay no problem :)

Comment: `td{ text-align:center;}` had no change from the css I had before using `.class` to call for the text alignment. I'm just going to give up, haha. I have no clue why a random amount of the captions are centering. Even in the WYSIWYG preview in Drupal it shows all of them as centered under the photos...the important part was getting the photos nice and lined up and that's been accomplished. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I just replaced your **CSS** with following and removed `style="..."` from `img`

```
img {
    width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/z64t6aj4/) JSFiddle demo.

Comment: Hm, [this is what it looks like now](http://i.imgur.com/C3hrdOW.png). I can't have the pictures be wider than the white space on the page, which is why my HTML had them resized. In your JSFiddle demo, I'm curious as to why that was removed. I also am not able to get the figcaptions centered under the pictures anymore. Here's what my CSS looks like:

`img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

figcaption {
  text-align: center;
  width: 360px;
}`

Comment: Try`td{  text-align:center;}` instead, check updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z64t6aj4/1/)